# sprite kit collisions not precise between 2 objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, physics

I have a red square which is affected by gravity and can jump on blue blocks coming from right to left. 
I consider these blocks being platforms,if the red square is on the top of the platform i don’t delete the platform, i only delete this one if the collision occurs on the left side.

I have one issue that i try to solve.

When the collision occurs on the top of the platform, to detect if it is on the top i write a condition to know if the down position of the red square is lower than the top of the platform i delete this one.

```
if(([SQUARE getDownPosY] < [PLATFORM getUpPosY]-5)){
    // Delete the blue platform 
}
```

i set the -5 because sometimes on collisions the square collide but enter in the platform( when the square jump is high more often or when the gravity of the scene is higher), even if i set the use precise collision on the 2 bodies.(i control the position in the methods didBeginContact).
But sometimes with this condition the wall is delete because it is more than 5 pixel inside the platform). The problem is that square is affected by gravity and fall down, and i think the collision is not detected precisely every pixel maybe every 6 7 pixel during the fall and if the last detection occurs 1 pixel between the platform and the square the next one is after 7 pixel and that is the reason why the condition is true.

I try to solve the problem by using the didBeginContact or didEndContact but it doesn’t change anything i think to solve the problem i need to handle the collision after the square is "  replaced " on the top by the physics simulator even if i don’t see on the screen any movement everything is right.

```
//Configuration of the physics body in Platform.m 

- (void)configureCollisionBody {

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBod bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.frame.size];    
    self.physicsBody.dynamic=NO;    
    self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;    
    self.physicsBody.mass=0.0f;    
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypePlatform;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypeSquare;
    self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection=YES;

}

//Configuration of the physics body in Square.m

- (void)configureCollisionBody {

    CGSize physicsBodySize=CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:physicsBodySize];
    self.physicsBody.allowsRotation=NO;
    self.physicsBody.mass=0.1f;
    self.physicsBody.dynamic=YES;
    self.physicsBody.restitution=0.0f;
    self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypeSquare;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypePlatform;
    self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection=YES;

}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried with showsPhysics enabled to see the actual collision shapes? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/showsPhysics

Comment: i edit my answer with a screenshot. the shapes are good

Comment: When i show the shape using showsPhysics the shape around the square the sure is blinking. But only when the square is on the top of the platform not during the jumping

Comment: are you scaling your objects?

Comment: no i don't i try to disable the gravity after collision and the blinking don't stop, it is the same i i let the square fall on the ground (red line) maybe it is normal ? to show the collision ?

Comment: i download this project on github and when you draw more physics some of them which are in contact are blinking too.
https://github.com/trentsartain/SwiftDrawnPhysics

and if you increase the gravity to -17 for example the first object you create will blink when it reaches the ground

Comment: i finally found how to solve my problem i perform some actions in didSimulate physics